# How can I pass a reference to a Transform object using Eigen3?

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I have a C++ function that takes as input a reference to a Transform object, but the compilation is terminated due to these errors

```
error: ‘IsVectorAtCompileTime’ is not a member of ‘const Eigen::Transform<double, 2, 2>’

error: template argument 3 is invalid
```

Here is my code:

```
template <typename Derived>
void Denormalize(Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>* camera_matrix, const Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::Affine2d>& T) {...} 

Eigen::Affine2d T; 
Denormalize(&camera_matrix, T);
```

The signature of Eigen's Ref class is as follows:

```
template<typename PlainObjectType, int Options, typename StrideType>
class Eigen::Ref< PlainObjectType, Options, StrideType >
```

And the [doc](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Ref.html) says: PlainObjectType is the equivalent matrix type of the mapped data.

I'm not sure whether the Transform type can be converted to the matrix type used in Eigen.

Can someone help me fix this problem?

Comment: The transform must be a matrix of size n by m say, and it operates on vectors of size n resulting in another vector of size m.

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

`Eigen::AffinexX` objects don't work with `Eigen::Ref`

### The Problem in Detail.

The [Eigen::Ref API](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Ref.html) gives PlainObjectType as the first input. But this is just a type *name*. If you look at [Line 31 in Ref.h](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/Ref_8h_source.html), we see the line that generates this error message - Ref is looking for the input class to have a member variable called "IsVectorAtCompileTime". Do a bit more digging and we see that [`PlainObjectBase`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1PlainObjectBase.html), and any class which inherits from it like `Matrix` and `Array`, will have this variable. See the [The Class Heirarchy](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicClassHierarchy.html) documentation for more information.

Now, if you look at the Eigen [Geometry Module](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-3.2/group__Geometry__Module.html#title6) API, you will see that the `Affine2d` type (and related types) are actually just typedefs of the class [`Eigen::Transform`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Transform.html) and that the underlying type (in your case) is `Eigen::Transform<double,2,Eigen::Affine>`. The `Transform` class doesn't inherit from any other Eigen class like `PlainObjectBase` or `Derived`. So it doesn't have that parameter "IsVectorAtCompileTime". That is why your function fails, and why it will fail if you try to input any `Transform` object to `Ref`.